# problems with get and actions\

Tags: php

So i have problem, for example, if create dashboard.php file and i use $GET for making multiple actions and not multiple files, it will look like dashboard.php?action=blablabla

but the problem is if on default page i put something and then go on action=blablabl the text from defauld dashboard.php will transfer to action page, example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN0JK.jpg

first is index page second is with action.

code:

```
function content_temp($con)
{

    echo "This is only on default page";


      if(isset($_GET['action']))
      {
          if($_GET['action'] == 'addticket')
          {
                echo '
                    <center><p>Popunite sva potrebna polja, molimo vas da postavljate samo preko potrebne stvari, za ostalo imate forum.</p></center>

                    <form method="post" action="#">

                    <input type="text" required placeholder = "Naslov" name="Naslov">

                    <center><select name="vrstaproblema">
                    <option value="Problemi sa racunom">Problemi sa racunom</option>
                    <option value="Problemi sa imovinom">Problemi sa imovinom</option>
                    <option value="Donacije">Donacije</option>

                    </select></center></br>


                    <center><textarea name="tickettext" required id="tickettext" cols="100" rows="14" placeholder ="Unesite vase pitanje ovde..."></textarea><br /><br /></center>
                    <input type="submit" name="add_ticket_button" value="Dodaj Ticket">
                    </form> 
                ';
          }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
function content_temp($con)
{
    if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
        echo "This is only on default page";
    } elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'addticket') {
        echo '
                <center><p>Popunite sva potrebna polja, molimo vas da postavljate samo preko potrebne stvari, za ostalo imate forum.</p></center>

                <form method="post" action="#">

                <input type="text" required placeholder = "Naslov" name="Naslov">

                <center><select name="vrstaproblema">
                <option value="Problemi sa racunom">Problemi sa racunom</option>
                <option value="Problemi sa imovinom">Problemi sa imovinom</option>
                <option value="Donacije">Donacije</option>

                </select></center></br>


                <center><textarea name="tickettext" required id="tickettext" cols="100" rows="14" placeholder ="Unesite vase pitanje ovde..."></textarea><br /><br /></center>
                <input type="submit" name="add_ticket_button" value="Dodaj Ticket">
                </form> 
            ';
        }
    } elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'do-something-else') {
        echo 'Something else';
    }
}
```